# Why does the Oruch HaShulchan tell the number of words in the blessings of the Amidah?

Tags: words, shemoneh-esrei, kavana-concentration

The Oruch HaShulchan (eg [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%97)) mentions how many words there are in each of the blessings of the weekday Amidah and gives a reason why that number of words is used.

For example for the blessing of *T'ka bashofar* he says:

> ויש בה עשרים תיבות (טור ופרי עץ חיים) כנגד פסוק: "וביום שמחתכם...
>   ותקעתם בחצוצרות...", שיש בו גם כן עשרים תיבות (טור סוף סימן קי"ז).
>
> And there are twenty words corresponding to the possuk “and on the day
>   of your rejoicing .. and you shall blow on the trumpets” which also
>   has 20 words.

Why does the  Oruch HaShulchan mention it? Is it somehow advisable to have this in mind when praying?

Comment: Or possibly an early implementation of a checksum? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum

Comment: Note that these word-count requirements are much older than Aruch HaShulchan, being recorded in the Tur.

Comment: Also, interestingly, many modern day _siddurim_ (especially _nusach sefard_) are not particular in following these word-count requirements. However, I remember hearing that R. Shneur Zalman of Liadi (the Alter Rebbe of Chabad) took care that his edition of the _siddur_ (the basis of today's so-called _nusach ari_) did meet these requirements.

Comment: Thinking about it, I wonder if this is the basis of an answer. The Aruch HaShulchan records these numbers simply to tell us to make sure that our _brachos_ actually contain these numbers of words.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14672/759

Comment: @JoelK They aren't word count requirements. They are word count reports.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to why the Aruch HaShulchan does this is found in [Orach Chaim 112:4 and 5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91) which states:

> **סימן קיב סעיף ד**[עריכה]
>   **כתב הטור בסימן קי"ג בשם אחיו רבינו יחיאל, דחסידי אשכנז היו מונין כל התיבות** **שבכל ברכה וברכה משמונה עשרה ברכות:** בברכה ראשונה ארבעים ושתים תיבות, בשניה חמשישים ואחת תיבות (זהו עם "משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם"), בשלישית ארבע עשרה, ברביעית שבע עשרה, בחמישית חמש עשרה, ובששית ובשביעית לא מנה מספר התיבות.
>
> **אבל בספר פרי עץ חיים להאר"י ז"ל (דף ס' ע"א) מנה גם כן התיבות,** וכתב
>   המספר שווה כהטור, עיין שם. וכתב דבששית עשרים תיבות, ובשביעית שבע עשרה,
>   עיין שם.
>
> (ובברכה ראשונה כתב ארבעים ושמונה, וזהו עם פסוק "ה' שפתי תפתח".)
>
> ובשמינית כתבו הטור והפרי עץ חיים עשרים ושבעה תיבות, ובתשיעית שלושים
>   תיבות, ובעשירית עשירים. ובאחת עשרה לא מנה הטור, ובפרי עץ חיים כתב
>   עשרים וארבע תיבות. ובשתים עשרה שהיא ברכת "ולמלשינים" כתבו עשרים ותשע
>   תיבות, ובשלוש עשרה ארבעים ושתים תיבות, ובארבע עשרה עשרים וארבע, ובחמש
>   עשרה עשרים. ובשש עשרה שהיא "שמע קולינו" לא מנה הטור, ובפרי עץ חיים כתב
>   שלושים וחמש תיבות. ובשבע עשרה ושמונה עשרה ותשע עשרה גם כן לא מנה הטור,
>   ובפרי עץ חיים כתב בשבע עשרה שלושים וארבע, ובשמונה עשרה שמונים ושש,
>   ובתשע עשרה גם בפרי עץ חיים אינו מבואר, עיין שם.
>
> **> והנה הטור כתב על כל זה רמזים וכוונות פשטיות, ובפרי עץ חיים כתב בזה
>   סודות גדולים ונוראים, עיין שם.**
>
> **סימן קיב סעיף ה**[עריכה] **והנה אם כי אין אתנו יודע עד מה, והלואי שנכוון
>   פירוש המילות כפשוטן. מכל מקום יש לכל איש ישראלי להבין גודל ערך תפילת
>   שמונה עשרה,** שהרי שמעון הצדיק היה משיורי כנסת הגדולה כדתנן בריש אבות,
>   וגודל מעלתו מפורסם בש"ס כמבואר ביומא (לט ב) ובריש תמיד. ועל אחת כמה
>   וכמה אנשי כנסת הגדולה עצמן, וקל וחומר הנביאים שביניהם.
>
> > ואם הם עמלו ברוח קדשם לסדר התפילה, כמה כוונות נוראות יש בהם! וכל תיבה
> >     ותיבה עומד ברומו של עולם. **ולכן אשרי האיש אשר יתפלל בשום לב להדברים
> >     הקדושים ההמה.**

The Aruch HaShulchan is following the custom of the [early Hasidei Ashkenazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashkenazi_Hasidim) and also the teachings of the Ari z"l. That custom is to count the words of each blessing in the Amidah. This counting is associated with the mystical intentions associated with prayer.

As he goes on to explain in seif 5, even though many of us may not know the specific mystical intentions associated with each blessing, and only understand the plain meaning of the words, it is meritorious for everyone to be aware that the blessings have specific, detailed arrangement and order according to these mysteries. And he praises the individual who sets their heart to pray according to these holy things, meaning to pray with the mystical intentions.

Comment: Notably, these numbers are not consistent across different traditions or even consistent within ashkenazi traditions. Also notable is that no one before the 13th century seems to have thought that keeping track of a specific number here was very important. Think of these like nice gematriot not original traditions from Sinai.

Comment: The Abudarham in his introduce says that he tried to check the number of words in each of the Berachot of the amida and next he renounced because of the lack of liability of the masoret concerning those numbers

Comment: @kouty Can you give a link to the page citation in the Avudarham. I would love to see his comments.

Comment: @kouty Yes, and the Rashba too proves that any words with the right idea is fine since if Chazal cared about specific Nusach they would have given us the number of words. It's true Chasidei Ashkenaz (who were really into symbology) did this stuff and attached lots of meaning to it, but it's hardly universally accepted as particularly significant. Some people took it to such an extreme that when they saw the word מהרה removed from the 17th blessing of the Amida, they just made up a new word to be added (את) in order to keep the count the same. Way to miss the point of a check sum!!