# Prayer beads among the Jewish Sages

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Prayer beads are commonly found in various religions as a tool for meditation and prayer.  Did Judaism ever have any religious use of prayer beads, perhaps among the Jewish Sages?  Or would this be considered halachically forbidden as a form of idolatry?

Comment: Consider clarifying what role these beads have in meditation.

Comment: Hi user16558, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Great question, perhaps it would be clearer if you provided an explanation of what prayer beads do in the context of prayer and/or meditation.

Comment: Prayer beads may be used as a counting mechanism to keep track of a prescribed set of prayers, and to heighten concentration on the prayers at hand.  They may serve to help the praying individual avoid distraction.

Comment: I would think that even if it had originally been used it would have been dropped as *chukas hagoyim* and therefore forbidden.

Comment: @user16558 The sages certainly did use esoteric practices for reaching higher states of consciousness. There is actually a series of books written by a now passed Rabbi by the name of Aryeh Kaplan. He conducted research into certain esoteric texts which delved into the practices. His books cover different concepts of Jewish meditation and how it was practiced. Some of them are meditations related to the Hebrew Alephbet and others are related to meditating on concepts related to Hashem's divinity. The books are a light read and you can get some functional exercises out of it.

Comment: @sabbahillel Not necessarily. We don't just drop minhagim like that just because someone after us randomly adopts something similar. We don't ditch the yarmulke because Catholics wear a similar hat.

Comment: I was thinking more like a matzeva which had been used by the avos for an altar and is now forbidden. Also the discussion about decorating the shul on Shavuos. There are other minhagim that were dropped because they became major elements of avodas zara.

Comment: @Avri I don't recall ever coming across mention/discussion of the use of prayer/worry beads in Kaplan's corpus. Do you know (if and) where exactly he does?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how else to answer this question but the answer is that beads have never played a part in Jewish worship. It's simply not the way that our prayers have been formatted. We don't need to "count" prayers like Catholics with rosary beads or the like.

Comment: See please the answer to my question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88024/why-does-the-oruch-hashulchan-tell-the-number-of-words-in-the-blessings-of-the-a "... the custom of the early Hasidei Ashkenazi and also the teachings of the Ari z"l. That custom is to count the words of each blessing in the Amidah. This counting is associated with the mystical intentions associated with prayer."

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Counting of words was also a way (a not so efficient one) to ensure that the blessings of the Amidah are not changed.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok that's not  a 'count while you pray' system though.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok And it wasn't done with beads...